# Demonstrate the height of the cone inscribed in a sphere as a function of the radius of the sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: A cone and a cylinder, both straight, have the same volume and identical bases. Knowing that both are inscribable in a sphere of radius R, what is the height H of the cone (as a function of R)?(A: $\frac{6R}{5}$)

I have not been able to demonstrate this relationship.

$r_{ci}=r_{co} = r\\
r_e=R\\
V_{ci}=V_{co}\implies \pi r^2.h_{ci}=\frac{1}{3}.\pi r^2.h_{ci}\\
\therefore h_{co}=3h_{ci}\\
V_e=\frac{4}{3}.\pi .R^3\\
R^2 = r^2+(h_{co}-R)^2\\
4R^2=h_{ci}^2+4r^2\implies h_{ci}^2=4(R^2-r^2)\\
(\frac{h_{co}}{3})^2=4(R^2-r^2)\implies h_{co}^2=36(R^2-r^2)\\
h_{co} = 6\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$

I don't see how to continue or even if the question's relationship can exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your work, we subtract the second equation from the first one and then we use the third one:
$$\begin{cases}
R^2 = r^2+(h_{co}-R)^2\\
R^2=\frac{h_{ci}^2}{4}+r^2\\
h_{co}=3h_{ci}
\end{cases}\implies h_{co}-R=\frac{h_{ci}}{2}=\frac{h_{co}}{6}
\implies h_{co}=\frac{6R}{5}.$$